# How can I call a method in parent view? (iPhone/ Objective-C)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a view that is used to update some NSUserDefaults. These defaults have an impact on a table in a different view. The issue I'm facing is that I want to reload the data in the table before the view is displayed again.

At present I have `viewA` which contains the table, I then display `viewB` using the following code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewB animated:YES];
```

Once the user has updated the NSUserDefaults `viewB` is dismissed, therefore displaying `viewA` again. Before `viewA` is displayed I want to be able to refresh the data though. Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: [Delegates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In viewA's viewWillAppear call you refresh code.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     // your refresh code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Via [delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html):

the ViewAController should implement a [protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Protocol.html), that the ViewBController offers

```
@protocol ViewBControllerProtocol
/*
use full signatures here
*/
@end


@interface ViewBController{
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<ViewBControllerProtocol> delegate;
@end;


@interface ViewAController <ViewBControllerProtocol>{
}
@end;

@implemantation ViewAController

// implement the method defined in the protocol
@end
```

then you do

```
viewB.delegate = viewA
```

You'll find a [sample code at github](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/VSCheckFavorites/Classes), where `CheckTableController` would be `ViewBController` and `ShowFavoritesTableController` `ViewAController`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `presentingViewController`/`parentViewController` (read the docs on these).  But a better all round solution is to make the "parent" the delegate of your modal controller, and have the parent implement a protocol that the delegate conforms to.

An even better solution is to present the modal controller with the return code in blocks, but you'll have to roll your own solution for that, as Apple haven't given us one yet.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you dismiss the modalViewController or viewB in a method in viewA, if viewAcontroller is your delegate for viewBcontroller.
In this same method, you only have to implement the table reload data you need, and this will be done before displaying viewA again.

I have that kind of code:

in viewBcontroller.h before the interface:

```
    @protocol ViewBControllerDelegate <NSObject>
   -(IBAction)closeViewBController;

    @end
```

in viewBcontroller.m:

```
    -(IBAction)closeView{


    [[self parentViewController] performSelector:@selector(closeViewBController)];

    }
```

In viewAcontroller.h:

```
    @interface viewAcontroller : UIViewController <ViewBControllerDelegate>
    {//....implementation here
```

and in ViewAController.m:

```
    -(IBAction)closeViewBController{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   //code needed if NSUserDefault is modified
    }
```

that is quite easy to write. Hope this will answer your question